# How to define content type when an loading image in as3 flex project?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

in flashCS3.app i think all you have to do is:

```
var thumb_url = my_images[i].@URL;
var thumb_loader = new Loader();
thumb_loader.load(new URLRequest(thumb_url));
```

but i am using flex + as3project.

how can i translate?
do i need some sort of bitmapdata class or is there a more transparent translation?
the error i get is something along the lines of "content type undefined".

thanks, 
jml

Comment: Try to explain this in more detail. I have no idea what you want or what have tried to do.

Comment: also pls use some static sample image for thumb_url. and clarify your question

Comment: Hi jml,

I've already had this error, when I was loading something else than a .swf, .gif, .jpg, or .png file. 
Are you sure you're "loading" one of these file types?

Cheers

Comment: Sorry; I've been away...  I am in fact loading one of those file types.  I will investigate further for the details on the URL and test those particulars first.  Thanks everyone for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, it'd help a lot, if you could provide a URL where it doesn't work ...

you cannot define the content type ... the content type should be defined by the server, in a HTTP response header ... however flash player usually ignores it and looks at the starting sequence to determine the loaded content type ...

as just_a_dude mentioned, the error you get, appears, when the file type is not supported ... what kind of image are you loading?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it was as simple as a bunk link.
sorry for the noise; i had a mal-formatted PHP string that was calling an image up.

Comment: I should also mention that the file was a standard .jpg and that there was nothing wrong with the type.